# Disable communication in ejabbderd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm using ejabberd as the basis for a notification service.

A user (we'll call it notifyme@server.com) acts as a bot, sending out notifications to the various users registered on the system.

I want to disable chat between users, so that they can only send and receive messages with notifyme@server.com and not each other.

I've achieved the rostering using a patch to ejabberd and shared rosters, so the only contact they can see is notifyme@server.com and they can't add more, but they are still able to send a message to another user and it will be received.

**TL;DR How can I make it so that users can only message users on their roster?**

Thanks for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make it so that users can only message users on their roster?

In a normal setup,  you can achieve that using a privacy list(xep-0016) rule that specifies you only want to send/receive messages from users on your roster.  But users can modify their privacy list,  so I guess that's not acceptable in your case.
You probably need to write a custom ejabberd module for your need, or modify mod_privacy to always enforce that rule and don't let the client modify it.